# Request Id from the Graph Call

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following code to get users from a group:

```
var response = await graphClient
                                .Groups[groupId]
                                .TransitiveMembers
                                .Request()
                                .Top(999)
                                .GetAsync();
```

How do I update the code to get the request id from the response?

UPDATE:

What about from this api call:

```
var response  = await graphClient
                                    .Groups
                                    .Delta()
                                    .Request()
                                    .Select("members")
                                    .Filter($"id  eq '{groupId}'")
                                    .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request id is part of the response headers. The name of the header is `request-id`. It can be accessed through `AdditionalData`.

```
var requestId = response.AdditionalData["responseHeaders"].GetValues("request-id").FirstOrDefault();
```

Latest version (>4.0) of `Microsft.Graph` client library has method `GetResponseAsync` which is some wrapper object that encapsulate information like response headers and status codes, so they can be easily accessible.

```
var graphResponse = await graphClient
                            .Groups[groupId]
                            .TransitiveMembers
                            .Request()
                            .Top(999)
                            .GetResponseAsync();
if (graphResponse.HttpHeaders.TryGetValues("request-id", out var values))
{
    var requestId = values.FirstOrDefault();
}
var responseObject = await graphResponse.GetResponseObjectAsync();
```

Comment: In my code, I use .GetAsync() I see you using .GetResponseAsync(). What is the difference?

Comment: As I wrote, GetResponseAsync is wrapper object that encapsulate information like response headers, status codes and the response object. GetAsync returns the response object. Use what is more comfortable for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the below doc to get response header - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/2.0/docs/upgrade-to-v4.md#graph-response:

Comment: Did you try your code? When using Graph API C# SDK, there is no property headers on the object return by await graphClient.Groups[groupId].TransitiveMembers.Request().Top(999).GetAsync();